# why the result of `yum deplist` and `yum install --downloadonly` is different?

Tags: linux, centos, yum, docker

When I run this:

`yum install -y --downloadonly --downloaddir=xxx docker-ce`,

then I got those rpm files:

```
container-selinux-2.188.0-1.module+an8.6.0+10825+318933f1.noarch.rpm
docker-ce-20.10.18-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
docker-ce-cli-20.10.18-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.18-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
docker-compose-plugin-2.10.2-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
docker-scan-plugin-0.17.0-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
fuse3-3.3.0-15.an8.x86_64.rpm
fuse3-libs-3.3.0-15.an8.x86_64.rpm
fuse-overlayfs-1.9-1.module+an8.6.0+10825+318933f1.x86_64.rpm
libcgroup-0.41-19.el8.x86_64.rpm
libslirp-4.4.0-1.module+an8.5.0+10624+8ab00a81.x86_64.rpm
slirp4netns-1.2.0-2.module+an8.6.0+10825+318933f1.x86_64.rpm
```

but when I run:
`yum deplist docker-ce | grep provider | uniq`

I got this:

```
   provider: bash-4.4.20-4.an8_6.x86_64
   provider: shadow-utils-2:4.6-16.an8.x86_64
   provider: container-selinux-2:2.188.0-1.module+an8.6.0+10825+318933f1.noarch
   provider: containerd.io-1.6.8-3.1.el8.x86_64
   provider: docker-ce-cli-1:20.10.18-3.el8.x86_64
   provider: docker-ce-rootless-extras-20.10.18-3.el8.x86_64
   provider: iptables-1.8.4-22.0.2.an8.1.x86_64
   provider: glibc-2.28-189.5.0.1.an8_6.x86_64
   provider: libcgroup-0.41-19.el8.x86_64
   provider: device-mapper-libs-8:1.02.181-3.0.1.an8_6.2.x86_64
   provider: glibc-2.28-189.5.0.1.an8_6.x86_64
   provider: libseccomp-2.5.2-1.0.1.an8.x86_64
   provider: systemd-libs-239-58.0.3.an8_6.7.x86_64
   provider: glibc-2.28-189.5.0.1.an8_6.x86_64
   provider: systemd-239-58.0.3.an8_6.7.x86_64
   provider: tar-2:1.30-5.0.2.an8.x86_64
   provider: xz-5.2.4-4.an8_6.x86_64
```

As far as I know, both above 2 commands can display dependent packages，

1. why the result is different？
2. How do I get the dependency list when I need to install Docker in a non network environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `yum install` selects all the *missing* dependencies, taking into account packages installed in the system, and processing all the given packages’ dependencies including transitive dependencies. `yum deplist` lists all the given package’s dependencies, including those which are already installed, and it doesn’t include transitive dependencies.
2. `yumdownloader --resolve --alldeps docker-ce` should download all of `docker-ce`’s dependencies for you, including those which are already installed.